# What does lambda event: do?

Tags: python, tkinter, lambda

What is the difference between `lambda:` and `lambda event:`. I did some research but can still not work out the difference.

Consider this code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

r = 0

def func(n):
    r = n

#works
b1 = tk.Button(root, text='1')
b1.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event: func(1))
b1.pack()

#does not work
b2 = tk.Button(root, text='2')
b2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda: func(2))
b2.pack()

tk.mainloop()
```

Why does button 2 work but not button 1? Specifically, I get this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: <lambda>() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Event is an argument to the lambda function. In other words, if you define

`x = lambda a: a+10`

You can run `x(10)` to get `20`.

You can’t, on the other hand, do

```
x = lambda: 10
x(10)
```

As that lambda function takes no arguments

Your error happens because tkinter tried to pass a positional argument to a lambda function that doesn’t take any.

Comment: What positional argument was tkinter trying to pass to the lambda function? Why is that needed?

Comment: It was attempting to pass an event. This event sometimes contains data that you may use, I.e. a mouse’s x/y position on a click event. See the documentation for the bind method for more detail.